# Forward declaring a static variable in C++

Tags: c++, extern, forward-declaration, static-variables

I run into the following problem and idk if it can be solved in an elegant way:

1. I need to statically initialize an interface `wifi` and `sntp` in main. I can't do it in global space because they are dependent on a task scheduler which is started only when main is called.
2. The wifi API takes a callback which requires the sntp interface to be present to start it, thus capturing it by reference.
3. The sntp service depends on the wifi service to be started as the wifi service will start up the network interface that sntp needs (I know this is bad design but I'm kind of fixed on this solution right now).

So I'm landing in cyclic dependency land once again. My initial thought to fight through this was to just forward declare the static variable but it turns out this doesn't work in the way that I thought, as declaring it "extern" conflicts with the later definition.

Here's the code:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Astruct+wifi_config+%7B%0A++++std::function%3Cvoid()%3E+callback%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+wifi+%7B%0A++++wifi(const+wifi_config%26+cfg)+%7B%7D+%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+sntp+%7B%0A++++sntp()++%3D+default%3B%0A%0A++++auto+start()+-%3E+void+%7B+printf(%22SNTP+start!!%5Cn%22)%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++extern+sntp+mysntp%3B%0A%0A++++static+wifi+mywifi(wifi_config%7B%0A++++++++.callback+%3D+%5B%26%5D()+-%3E+void+%7B%0A++++++++++++mysntp.start()%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D)%3B%0A%0A++++static+sntp+mysntp%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.597812879708385,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:38.949671772428886,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:61.050328227571114,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.402187120291615,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

struct wifi_config {
    std::function<void()> callback;
};

struct wifi {
    wifi(const wifi_config& cfg) {} 
};

struct sntp {
    sntp()  = default;

    auto start() -> void { printf("SNTP start!\n"); }
};

int main() {

    extern sntp mysntp;

    static wifi mywifi(wifi_config{
        .callback = [&]() -> void {
            mysntp.start();
        }
    });

    static sntp mysntp;
}
```

And here's the error:

```
<source>:28:17: error: 'sntp mysntp' conflicts with a previous declaration
   28 |     static sntp mysntp;
      |
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: I may be missing something, but you already need the initialization of `mysntp` to happen before the callback is called (or calling `start` is definitely undefined). So why can't it be declared first, again?

Comment: In above example `sntp` doesn't depends of `wifi`, you don't have cycle.

Comment: There is no such thing like "Forward declaring a static variable". "Forward declarations" are for types (struct/class) and its templates. What exactly are you trying achieve from end user point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most painless way is to put them both as members of the same struct. The order the members are declared in the struct is the order that they are constructed in:

```cpp
int main() {
    struct statics {
        wifi mywifi{
            wifi_config{
                .callback = [this]() -> void {
                    mysntp.start();
                }
            }
        };

        sntp mysntp;
    };
    static auto [ mywifi, mysntp ] = statics();

}
```

This has very slightly different semantics if one of the constructors were to throw, but this shouldn't be a problem in `main()`.

Also, a static in `main` is kind of useless because they will be destroyed when main exits, very similarly to if they had been automatic variables. If you were to switch to automatic variables, you could just remove the `static` in `static auto [ ...`.

---

To answer your question literally, it is possible to "forward declare" static variables (get a reference to them before they have been initialized):

```cpp
int main() {
    // fake "forward declaration"
    constexpr auto get_mysntp = [](sntp init()){
        static sntp mysntp(init());
        return std::integral_constant<sntp*, &mysntp>{};
    };
    constexpr sntp& mysntp = *decltype(get_mysntp(nullptr))::value;

    static wifi mywifi(wifi_config{
        .callback = [&]() -> void {
            mysntp.start();
        }
    });

    // fake "definition" (actually construct the static variable)
    get_mysntp([]{ return sntp{}; });
}
```

Which may be useful if your example is more complicated. The `struct` of statics is probably enough.

Comment: "Also, a static in main is kind of useless because they will be destroyed when main exits" Are you sure about this? I thought the point of all statics is to be preserved across function calls.

Comment: @glades main is the first function to be called and the last function to be left, all statics are destroyed after it finishes

Comment: Ah forgot to explain. Yes in blank cpp, but I'm running this on an RTOS microprocessor which has a app_main() instead of main() which is invoked by main(). The statics remain valid throughout the program.

Answer (score 2):

It if it is `extern` you are saying that mysntp is defined in another compilation unit. By declaring it `static` you are declaring it and saying it is only available in this compilation unit (cpp file). Those are not compatible.

Comment: not correct, `extern` can refer to same translation unit.

Comment: Nono that just Emits a weak symbol to the linker afaik. For example you can do this: https://godbolt.org/z/6dcYnY9rG

Comment: @glades it doesn't refer to function local static though.

Comment: @appleapple Unfortunately

Comment: @glades not exactly, you have order inside same function. globals are another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? (TBH, I'm not sure if it does, it depends when the callback is called.)

```
int main() {
    static sntp *mysntp_ptr;

    static wifi mywifi(wifi_config{
        .callback = [&]() -> void {
            mysntp_ptr->start();
        }
    });

    static sntp mysntp;
    mysntp_ptr = &mysntp;
}
```